# JBPM 7.31 catch reassign event

Tags: events, try-catch, jbpm, reassign

in JBPM is possible to catch a reassign event?
Example
a Human Task is assign to user JOHN, administrator user call kie-server REST API to reassign Human Task to MARK.
Is possible to catch the reassignment event in order to send notification or change some task parameter?

Answer (score 2):

You can write customTaskEventListener by implementing interface [TaskEventListener](https://github.com/kiegroup/droolsjbpm-knowledge/blob/7.x/kie-api/src/main/java/org/kie/api/task/TaskLifeCycleEventListener.java#L70) and use 'afterTaskReassignedEvent' to send notification or to change some task variables.